# Mqtt No such host is known error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mqtt

I am developing mqtt protocol based application in .net core application i develop the application using below link
[mqtt](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-m2mqtt)

my code is

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MqttClient client = new MqttClient("broker.hivemq.com");
  byte code = client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "username", "password");
  Console.WriteLine("code " + code);
  client.MqttMsgPublished += client_MqttMsgPublished;            
  ushort msgId = client.Publish("mytopic", // topic
     Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hai this is sample chat application"), // message body
     MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, // QoS level
     true); // retained
 Console.WriteLine("msgId " + msgId);
 client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

 void client_MqttMsgPublished(object sender, MqttMsgPublishedEventArgs e)
 {
   Debug.WriteLine("MessageId = " + e.MessageId + " Published = " + e.IsPublished);
   Console.WriteLine("MessageId = " + e.MessageId + " Published = " + e.IsPublished);
 }

 void client_MqttMsgSubscribed(object sender, MqttMsgSubscribedEventArgs e)
 {
   Debug.WriteLine("Subscribed for id = " + e.MessageId);
   Console.WriteLine("Subscribed for id = " + e.MessageId);
 }

 void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
 {
   Debug.WriteLine("Received = " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message) + " on topic " + e.Topic);
   Console.WriteLine("Received = " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message) + " on topic " + e.Topic);
 }
```

}

subscriber code:

```
mosquitto_sub -h broker.hivemq.com -t mytopic(terminal)
```

when I run this application the message send to subscriber but when I trying to publish message from terminal my application doesn't receive any message

published code in terminal

```
mosquitto_pub -h broker.hivemq.com -t mytopic -m "Hai this is sample"
```

So how to receive published message from terminal?

I am using mqtt client as `MqttClient client = new MqttClient("broker.hivemq.com");`

when I trying to change my ip address it didn't run getting error like

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
```

Answer (score 1):

working fine with below code

```
string[] topic = { "mytopic"};
byte[] qosLevels = { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE };
client.Subscribe(topic, qosLevels);
```

the above code was missing in my code.Terminal to c# console and c# console to terminal.

Comment: but still when using ipaddress getting same error. please give any idea?